# Если направить мышку на кнопку должна появиться panel

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

Нужно чтобы когда пользователь направил курсор на `button1` автоматически отобразилась `panel1` и когда курсор уйдет с `button1` и `panel1`, то `panel1` должна скрыться.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

В конструкторе формы устанавливаете видимость `panel1`:

```
     public Form1()
     {
         InitializeComponent();
         panel1.Visible = false;
     }
```

У элементов управления есть событие `MouseLeave` (когда указатель мыши выходит за границы элемента). У Вас это событие для `panel1`:

```
    private void panel1_MouseLeave(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        panel1.Visible = false;
    }
```

И также есть "обратное" событие `MouseEnter` (когда курсор входит в видимые границы элемента). В Вашем случае - для `button1`:

```
    private void button1_MouseEnter(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        panel1.Visible = true;
    }
```